# Query Java doesn't execute

Tags: java, sql, database, crud

I'm trying to execute a query on eclipse at my Java program, but it always exit with a exception and don't execute the query, I read a lot of posts here but no one of them could help me with this.

```
public static ResultSet queryAccAmount;

public static String query = " SELECT COUNT(*) s FROM (SELECT  L.ACCNUMBER AS AN, L.PROD AS PRD " 
        + " FROM LTRANS(nolock) L, AN(nolock) ANM " 
        + " WHERE DATA BETWEEN 20210101 AND 20210228 " 
        + " AND L.PRD IN (1, 2, 3) " 
        + " AND L.ACCNUMBER = ANM.ACCNUMBER "
        + " AND L.ISS = ANM.ISS " 
        + " AND L.PROD = ANM.PROD " 
        + " AND L.MESSAGECODE <> 'MESSAGE' "
        + " GROUP BY L.PROD, L.ACCNUMBER) S; ";

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Connection c = connect();

        int accAmount = 0;
        
        try {
            queryAccAmount = c.createStatement().executeQuery(query);

            accAmount = Integer.parseInt(queryAccAmount.getString(1));
            LOG.info("Mounth total: " + accAmount);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } finally {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            disconnect();
        }
}
```

The error when execute the program:

[JavaError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKf9U.png)

But at the base have data:

[DataBase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln12n.png)

I don't know what is wrong with this, who could help me I'm already appreciate!

Comment: Sorry, I'm from Brazil my code was in portuguese, I translated to post and I forget this variable name.

Comment: Please check [JDBC.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row](//stackoverflow.com/q/20900819)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call executeQuery once and then read the results in loop for example Updating my comment with working example:-

```
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCConnector {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "root";
   static final String PASS = "mysql";
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

Comment: It still not getting a result from the query, and giving the same exception

Comment: @LeonardoManzini I have updated my comments with working example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked very well!! Apreciate again

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in your try:

```
try {queryAccAmount = c.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        if(queryAccAmount.next){

        accAmount = Integer.parseInt(queryAccAmount.getString(1));}

        LOG.info("Mounth total: " + accAmount);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
        disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't enter the if condition but I have data at the base, looks like it don't read the data